# \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} doesn't use cm-super or cm-super unicode despite being installed

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Some Bitmap font is being used instead.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Expected output:
Pretty text that isn't cancer.

What I get:
Cancer. See logfile.

Logfile:
[Clicky](https://pastebin.com/anwE8X67)

[My updmap.cfg](https://pastebin.com/Bx46EHwB)

Comment: @Sveinung that is not true, in TeXLive cm-super is normally the default.

Comment: What exactly have you installed? Is this a repackaged TeXLive for slackware? Did you install all of it or just parts of it?

Comment: What does `kpsewhich sfrm1000.pfb` report? When I compile your MWE using my installation of upstream TeXLive then this font file is being listed as being included. Your installation is a bit strange, as I have a much newer lipsum installed

Comment: kpsewhich sfrm1000.pfb:
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb

Also, yeah ,it's a Slackware thing, from slackbuilds.org, but the base package has made it into the current snapshot.
The "extras" package is a huge one with all sorts of, well, extra packages. I installed everything.

Comment: how about `kpsewhich cm-super-t1.enc`, otherwise try installing upstream TL instead (tug.org/texlive). I usually recommend to not installing it as root, but rather install it as yourself in a folder you own in say `/opt`, and then adding this path to the $PATH variable.

Comment: `kpsewhich cm-super-t1.enc` gets:
`/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc`

Also, yes, I think I'll just scrap this entire thing and go the opt way, which was what I used before the merge of texlive into Slackware. Thanks.

Comment: Then it sounds like a misconfiguration somewhere, no idea where.

Comment: Dang, well, I purged the entire circus and I'm going back to the TL installer and all that. What a pain, wasting peoples time over something completely unrelated.

Comment: maybe you installed only `cm-super-minimal` then you will need to add `\usepackage[10pt]{type1ec}` before `fontspec` loading.

Comment: @Sveinung my firefox has no issue with pastebin. It said: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018 on Slackware) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.12.1)  5 DEC 2018 14:57`. What exactly do you mean with pastebin being improperly configured?

Comment: @Sveinung then you should probably look into that. Even my Chrome has no issues with it.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out the package of my distribution (Slackware 14.2-current) was faulty.
Getting rid of it and going full TL upstream fixed the issue.